# Error installating MVVM Light libraries only (PCL)

Tags: mvvm-light

I create a new PCL project, select Store app + Phone 8 + .Net 4.5
Then, from pakage manager console, I do:

```
Install-Package Portable.MvvmLightLibs -Pre
```

but it is not installed, I get an error. What I am doing wrong?

Thank you

The error message is:

Install-Package : Could not install package 'Portable.MvvmLightLibs 4.1.24-beta3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that 
targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that 
framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Portable.MvvmLightLibs -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but upgrading NuGet (currently 2.2) seems to have done the trick.